# How to open PDF from a specific path automatically?

Tags: android, pdf, firebase-storage

I have a android app that download pdf files from firebase, my problem is open the pdfs after the download. I would like to use the PDF Viewer library and open the pdf automatically after the download. This is possible? How would I do that?
Ps: I can save and get the path where the pdf were saved.

```
 File localFile = File.createTempFile("Pdfs", "pdf");
                downloadPDF.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        File localFile = getContext().getFilesDir();
                        String path= localFile.toString(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ pdffilename);
```

save pdf internal or external directory and set PDF path to PDF Viewer library. Check how to set Pdf path in PDF Viewer library.

Comment: Sorry, but do you know someway to save in internal memory? Using your code the file will be saved in the external memory, right?

Comment: you are using my code than your file save in internal directory.